# Reading .TDMS files that possess a time interval/duration

Tags: c#

I am trying to develop an application to read .tdms (National Instruments) files, for which I'm using the "TDMSReader" package [link to the package + use](https://github.com/mikeobrien/TDMSReader). This works fine except for those files which use a set duration or time interval.

In the .tdms example file [I'm providing](http://speedy.sh/GAdKM/tdms-file-example.zip) it can be noted that the file consists of five channels, each of which holds 174080 items.
(The content of the file can be viewed with this [excel add-in](http://www.ni.com/example/27944/en/))

However, the C# package I mentioned doesn't take this into account, it can only read the amount of items equal to the "wf_samples" field (10240), discarding the rest. Has anyone found a solution on how read the "Length" property of the channel and extract the rest of the array values?

Example of my code to convert a .tdms file to .csv

```
                //file.Fullname = full path to the .tdms file
                using (var output = new StreamWriter(File.Create(file.FullName + ".csv")))
                using (var tdms = new NationalInstruments.Tdms.File(file.FullName))
                {
                    tdms.Open();
                    List<object[]> All_Values = new List<object[]>();

                    //Headers
                    string channels = "";
                    foreach (var group in tdms)
                    {
                        foreach (var channel in group)
                        {
                            channels = channels + channel.Name + ";";
                            All_Values.Add(channel.GetData<object>().ToArray());
                        }
                    }
                    output.WriteLine(channels);

                    //Values
                    long cnt = tdms.First().Channels.First().Value.DataCount;
                    for (int i = 0; i < cnt; i++)
                    {
                        string values = "";
                        foreach (object[] columnValues in All_Values)
                        {
                            values = values + columnValues[i] + ";";
                        }
                        output.WriteLine(values);
                    }
                }
```

Any other alternative that provides a way to read .tdms files with C# is welcome.

EDIT: TDMS sample files:

[NO Interval sample](http://speedy.sh/vZzuQ/Tdms-sample-file-NO-INTERVAL.zip) 
This one works fine

[Interval Sample](http://speedy.sh/GAdKM/tdms-file-example.zip)
This one discards most of the array values

Comment: You should provide a tdms sample file

Comment: I did in the second link, I'll paste it here again: http://speedy.sh/GAdKM/tdms-file-example.zip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have submitted a PR for a fix to https://github.com/mikeobrien/TDMSReader. Mike has made a new release on https://www.nuget.org/packages/TDMSReader/.